# Styling source code blocks with pygments.css in Org mode -> HTML export (Pelican)

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm using the [org-mode reader](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/org_reader) for [Pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/) to generate articles for my blog (Export to HTML). Code blocks in Markdown version of the article look perfect but I cannot enable [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) for org-mode.

Is there any way to process org-mode code blocks using Pygments?

P.S I know about Pandoc but I need a more emacs-way solution to be able to customize export options using Emacs Lisp, not Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution to my issue and described full explanation [in my blog](https://linevi.ch/en/org-pygments.html?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=org_pygments).

In a few words, I've created custom export backend and pass the block contents to an external script.

```
(require 'org)
(require 'ox)
(require 'ox-html)

;; Path for pygments or command name
(defvar pygments-path "pygmentize")

(defun pygments-org-html-code (code contents info)
  ;; Generating tmp file path.
  ;; Current date and time hash will ideally pass our needs.
  (setq temp-source-file (format "/tmp/pygmentize-%s.txt"(md5 (current-time-string))))
  ;; Writing block contents to the file.
  (with-temp-file temp-source-file (insert (org-element-property :value code)))
  ;; Exectuing the shell-command an reading an output
  (shell-command-to-string (format "%s -l \"%s\" -f html %s"
                   pygments-path
                   (or (org-element-property :language code)
                       "")
                   temp-source-file)))

(org-export-define-derived-backend 'pelican-html 'html
  :translate-alist '((src-block .  pygments-org-html-code)
             (example-block . pygments-org-html-code)))
```

You can use these org reader variables to load the emacs functions in pelican:

```
ORG_READER_EMACS_SETTINGS = os.path.abspath('lisp/config.el')
ORG_READER_BACKEND = "'pelican-html"
```

Comment: Can you post the code here, please?